# Change color of whole Divi wordpress page globally

Tags: wordpress, divi

I'm working on a webpage for a client which will be a customizable template later on for other clients. Since the newest divi update with the global colors feature, I'm applying all the colors to global colors, so I'm able to change the color schemes more easily in future.

Now we have a lot of custom shortcodes which are connected to our software on the webpage and I'm wondering how I could change all the colors of elements which are no divi elements. (Our custom shortcodes are do only have html, we are applying the css within the divi page css if its just embedded on one page or customizer if it is used more often)

I already tried plugins like Better Search Replace and tried to change the color from red to blue for example. This doesnt work.

So does anybody know ho we can change the css code

- inside Divi Code Modules
- inside custom css of page
- inside theme builder global header and footer
- on any other place ?

Comment: This question should be directed to theme developers.

Comment: Im using divi. There is no theme developer. We are creating our own theme based on divi by elegantthemes

Comment: Divi is paid application with its own support platform. Not to mention is a niche product, the chance of people knowing the answer is very small.

Comment: Thanks for he answer, alright then..